# Adding data to a listView using custom CursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, listactivity, simplecursoradapter

Hi I want to achieve the following result in my ListActivity:

1. First item, descritpion
2. Second item, description
3. ...

where Name and description come from

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(...);
```

I used a *SimpleCursorAdapter* and I had no problems. Then I decided to make some modification to data that I have in cursor before displaying it. I wanted to have a internal counter that would increment every time cursor adapter dislays a new view. That's why I decided to implement my own *CustomCursorAdapter* extending *SimpleCursorAdapter*:

```
public class TrainingsListCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

private Context context;
private int layout;


int list_item_order_number = 1;

public TrainingsListCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
        String[] from, int[] to) {


    super(context, layout, c, from, to);

    this.context = context;
    this.layout = layout;



}//contructor


@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent){
    Cursor c = getCursor();

    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View v = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);

    String durationCol      = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("duration"));

    if(durationCol != null){
        durationCol = minutesForSeconds(durationCol);
    }


    TextView textViewDuration = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.duration);
    TextView order_number = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_num);


    if(order_number != null){
        order_number.setText(String.valueOf(list_item_order_number));

    }
    if(textViewDuration != null){
        textViewDuration.setText(durationCol);

    }


    list_item_order_number++;

    return v;

}
```

I have a member variable _list_item_order_number_ that is incremented by one every time a view/row is drawn (by calling newView() method). This number is displayed in every view/list item and it corresponds to list item order...

The problem I have is that when I'm rotating the screen this number doesn't correspond to list items anymore. For example my 3rd item has value 1 and so on...

I guess this has something to do with the order Android is drawing the views. If I scroll the list to, let's say, the middle and then rotate, these numbers are all mixed like this:

1. First Item
2. Second item
3. Third item